# How to load a spring mvc view template from a jar file

Tags: java, spring, templates, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

I have a relatively large web project and to simplify the develop process, I decide to split the project into several modules (jar projects with model, controller & views inside). 
I noticed that servlet 3.0 support automatic expose resource from jar file in **META-INF/resources** directory.

How to enforce spring mvc load view template from the jar's **META-INF/resources** directory?

I know the static resources can load by configuration

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources" />
```

The view resolver in my main module like below

```
<bean       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

It seemed nowhere can specify the view path from a jar.

I want same view loaded from main module's **/WEB-INF/jsp**, and same loaded from **META-INF/resources** of jar files, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory a prefix of '/' and suffix of '.jsp' should suffice. Resources from the `/META-INF/resources` directory are by default accesible (unless you override the default servlet). However those resources are available by default (as specified in section 10.5 of the Servlet 3.0 specification) and I'm not sure you want to be able to directly access the JSP (it still is better to place those somewhere inside the `/WEB-INF` directory.

Links:
- [Servlet 3.0 Specs](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr315/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for response. I'd like to know if I put a template in jar file using **META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/a.jsp** directory, it is just like if I put template in the web root **/WEB-INF/jsp/a.jsp** in a unpacking form?

Comment: Yes, it works under tomcat 7.0.28, but without success under jetty-8.1.12.v20130726. 


It throws a NullException under jetty: Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:205)
 at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:171)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:474)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)

Comment: In theory that might work, but as you already discovered it might depend on the Servlet Container one uses and how they interpret that part of the spec.